# Is there a way to show every result of a for loop in a discord embed's description

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to create a discord embed that shows a list of all the players online on a Minecraft server. I want the player names to be on their own separate line

But I'm unable to create a list such as that when I am trying to use a for loop to loop through every player in a dictionary/array, the embed only catches the first player in the list. Is there a way to show a player list with each player name on its own line, one by one?

```
players = json_data["players"]["list"]
                global player
                for player in players:
                    print(player)
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Online Players", description=player, url="",                       color=discord.Color.blue())
                await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `join` function.

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title="Online Players", description="\n".join(players), url="", color=discord.Color.blue())
```